# How can I remove characters from a StringBuffer?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am trying to make an encryption program and part of this includes having a passcode displayed at the beginning of my encrypted text and then displaying the alphabet after that with the letters contained in the passcode being removed from the alphabet.  I am trying to remove the characters in the passcode from my alphabet StringBuffer but it seems like there is no easy way to do this.  There is no method that automatically searches a method for all occurences of a character but there is for a String object.  However, I must replace a character with another character and I want to replace a character with nothing(essentially delete it).  This is my code:  Any help would be appreciated.

```
StringBuffer alphabet = new StringBuffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        for(int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++)
        {
           char replacedletter = pass.charAt(i);
           alphabet.replace(replacedletter,"");
        }
        System.out.println(pass + alphabet);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#deleteCharAt(int)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
StringBuffer s=...
for(char c: passcode.toCharArray()){
   int index=-1;
   while((index=s.indexOf(c))!=-1){
     s.deleteCharAt(index);
   }
}
```

Comment: But I do not know the index of the character that I want to delete.

Comment: What about StringBuffer.deleteCharAt(buf.indexOf("char"))?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate which version of java you are using but in 7 StringBuffer does have a [replace method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

```
replace(int start, int end, String str)
```

> Replaces the characters in a substring of this sequence with characters in the specified String.

Combine this with the `indexOf` method to replace all occurrences.

```
int ndx = alphabet.indexOf(String.valueOf(replacedLetter), 0);
while (ndx > -1) {
    alphabet.replace(ndx, ndx + 1, "");
    ndx = alphabet.indexOf(String.valueOf(replacedLetter), ndx);
}
```

Comment: This. And convert `char` to `String` with `String.valueOf(replacedLetter)`

Comment: The `replace` method doesn't do what the questioner is looking for, though. It replaces a subtring starting and ending at specified indices, whereas the questioner wants to replace all occurrences of a given string.

Comment: It is alphabet, all letters supposed to be unique. Find a position in alphabet with `int index = alphabet.indexOf(String.valueOf(replacedLetter))`, then replace `alphabet.replace(index, index + 1, "")`

Comment: This does not answer my question because as user2357112 said, I do not know the start and end of the substring for each letter I want to delete.  I want to delete all occurrences of the character in the string.

Comment: @skateboard34 But you can find it using `indexOf`, as shown in both of the answers so far.